# paypal ipn and custom will not add custom variable to database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

i've been try to pass custom variable though Paypal ipn but it does not add what was in inside the custom variable. look at the database it just leaves it blank.

here is my input the pass the custom variable to Paypal

```
echo '<input type = "hidden" name="custom_'.$num.'" value= "'.$get_row['file'].'">';
```

here is my ipn code

```
$filename=$_POST['custom'];
```

here where I tell in to put in in the datebase

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ibn_table
        (itransaction_id,ipayerid,iname,iemail,itransaction_date, ipaymentstatus,ieverything_else,nameofitem,itemNumber,filename)
        VALUES
        ('$transaction_id','$payerid','$firstname $lastname','$payeremail','$mdate', '$paymentstatus','$otherstuff','$nameofitem','$itemNumber','$filename')";
```

any help would be nice thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [variable reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) the field should simply be named `custom`. It should be passed back to you via IPN and PDT the same way.